# What will it return new Date( DateObject )?

Tags: javascript, date

`var DateObj = new Date(dateString);
 var Date = new Date(DateObj);`

What actually is the Date? Is it still a date object like this?

I just saw this code in the project which I'm working on, so I'm curious what it actually does. Also, I would not do this, but I want to know why don't do it?

Comment: Use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(dateString);
```

will return an instance of a Date Object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

```
new Date(DateObj)
```

returns a Date Object

your Date variable will now be set to an instance of the Date Object. In this scope you would now have effectively overridden the Date Object.

don't do this.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is good either, but I saw it somewhere, and I just want to know the reason that don't do this?

Answer (score 0):

> What actually is the Date? Is it still a date object like this?

It's quite easy to check using [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator:

```
var DateObj = new Date();
var DateObj2 = new Date(DateObj);

console.log(DateObj2 instanceof Date); // true
```

So the short answer is yes, it's will be `Date` instance.

Longer answer. If you are interested in what exactly happens if you pass Date object into `new Date` constructor, you need to refer ECMAScript specification.

Section [15.9.3.2 new Date(value)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) describes behavior:

1. Let *v* be [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)(*value*).

So the very first step of the algorithm requires that passed value to be converted to a primitive value. For Object types (like Date) primitive value is a ["default value for the Object"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8). And finally, for Date objects both [`valueOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) and `toString` methods returns a number - [current timestamp](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8).